# Answers embedded in questions by low rep users

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users, edits

I've been "working" the unanswered question queue in VB.NET and have come across quite a few questions with answers either embedded in the question body (by the OP) or answers in the comments section (either posted by the OP or, more rarely, another user).

In accordance with standing norms, I've create community wiki answers to these questions, "fixing" the problem:

- [What to do when OP answers his/her own question in an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74101/191410)
- [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54718/191410)

These kinds of issues seem pretty common for low-rep users. Scrolling the results on the unanswered list, I can usually guess whether or not this issue will be present based on the OP's rep.

**Part I: Is an "Improperly" Answered Question a Problem?**

I'm making the assumption that *not* having an actual answer posted is going to turn away some (most?) inexperienced users who are looking for an answer. (Would you bother reading a post if it says there are 0 answers?) For those with insider information (looking at you, SO devs/mods) or more experience, does this assumption hold any water? Or does an answer edited into the question/left in the comments not present too much of an issue?

**Part II: Finding these Sorts of Questions**

If my assumptions are correct and it *is* actually valuable to edit these questions, is there anything we could do to make them easier to find? I'd like to be able to search for unanswered questions posted by low-rep users using [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but I'm afraid this sort of feature [might be abused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182581/191410).

Is there any way that we could flag low-rep<sup>1</sup> users' edits to their own questions for review? Not that the edit would require approval - it would just give volunteers like myself an opportunity to review edits to look for these kinds of beginner mistakes. This would be very similar to the First Posts review queue (no *approvals* needed - just gives volunteers an opportunity to check for quality).

Again, the value of this feature-request is highly contingent on my assumption from **Part I** being true.

<sup>1</sup> I'm thinking < 40, though that could be tuned based on review results.

Comment: A much larger number of people are finding these types of questions through google, not SO search, and on Google you need to go to the question to see if it has an answer.  That's why I do fix these posts when I come across them, but I don't consider it worthwhile to go hunting for them.

Comment: From what I've seen, many posts by <40 rep users need *several* edits before they are even acceptable. I have a feeling a review queue for that would grow very rapidly, and the signal-to-noise ratio would make it useless. For searching, a combination of "solved" in the title and no answers is an immediate red flag.

Comment: I don't really have a good answer, but I do think it's a good idea to try and fix these, as it's helpful to people who find the questions later.  Try searching for terms like [is:question answers:0 body:"solved" closed:no](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0+body%3A%22solved%22+closed%3Ano) and you'll find a lot of questions that can either be closed or fixed.  That turns up over 3000 results, so you can add tags to narrow it down a bit. (I get 5000+ more results if I substitute "fixed" for "solved" in that query.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a new "review" queue is a workable solution as it would get too cluttered up by real edits to be able to mine out the answer edited into the question.

When I've gone looking for them in the past, searching titles for ["Solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:%22solved%22) or ["Answered"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22Answered%22) seems to work well, but does pick up a fair share of false positives.

The real solution might be Data Explorer.  If we can come up with the correct set of trigger words and phrases, someone who knows SQL better than me might be able to come up a query to help identify these posts far better than weeding through a list of editing questions.

Potential triggers might be:

- "Solved" or "Answered" in the title
- Phrases like "This is my solution" or "This is how I solved it" in the body

It would take more studying of these posts and some trial and error to help identify them though.

Comment: I had considered an approach like this and I've used DE before, but a `LIKE '%term%'` query is *very* expensive and I wouldn't want to run it regularly (or have lots of people run it regularly).

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 Frankly, I don't think it happens often enough that if you run the query once every few months, you can probably weed out the questions pretty quickly.